# Getting non-custom attribute in JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I embedded investing.com iframe into my site, but could not take exchange rate which in `main-value` attribute of element.

```
<div class="left instName js-col-pair_name afterGreenBg" main-value="5.7939">...</div>
```

I understand that custom `data-*` attributes are preferable, but this code is from an external site which I do not control

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: `$('.instName').attr('main-value')`, check [this](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use custom `data-*` prefix attributes, which can easily be fetched using [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property or jQuery's [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.left');
console.log(elem.dataset.mainValue);


var element = $('.left');
console.log(element.data('mainValue'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left instName js-col-pair_name afterGreenBg" data-main-value="5.7939">...</div>
```

---

Otherwise, use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) native method or jQuery's [`.attr(attributeName)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) method to get attribute value

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.left');
console.log(elem.getAttribute('main-value'));


var element = $('.left');
console.log(element.attr('main-value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left instName js-col-pair_name afterGreenBg" main-value="5.7939">...</div>
```

Comment: custom data-* is preferable but this code from external site